# Android SDK: Can't modify TextView from a DialogFragment

Tags: android

I've read a lot regarding this issue, but I don't get to get my case working.

I have defined a TextView element with an initial text in the XML layout file.

If I try to modify it from the main activity class (FragmentActivity) by doing next:

```
TextView domainText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.domainText);
domainText.setText("test");
```

it works perfectly.

But if I try to modify this very TextView element from a DialogFragment launched from my main activty class (FragmentActivity):

```
public class QueryDomainDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

...

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle(R.string.queryTypeDialogTitle)
           .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.queryDomains, 0, new           DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){

                   ListView lw = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView();
                   Object selectedDomain = lw.getAdapter().getItem(lw.getCheckedItemPosition());

                   LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, null);
                   TextView domainText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.domainText);

                   domainText.setText("test2");
               }
           })
```

nothing happens.

How should I do it? Am I doing it the wrong way? Isn't possible to modify elements from a DialogFragment? Should I implement a sort of callback?

I would like to know why isn't possible to modify elements such as TextView from a DialogFragment, if that's the case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were do you add the inflated view to your layout?

Answer (score 0):

By doing inflate you are not refering to the same text view any more, you need to set the exact same view, not a new inflated one..
You cannot refere to the textview from the dialog as it's not a part of it's layout..

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, null);
TextView domainText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.domainText);
```

You need to create a listener, make your activity implement this listener, and pass it to the dialog..

```
@Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){

               listener.setText("test2");
           }
```

Comment: But where do I get the inflater object from onCreateDialog method of a DialogFragment?

Comment: you don't need to inflate anything, it's already in the activity's layout

Comment: If I put "View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, null);" into onCreateDialog method of my DialogFragment class (which is not the main activity class) I get an "inflater cannot be resolved" error message.